# Rota de view não consegue ser exibida em yii

Tags: php, yii2

Boa tarde.

Eu estou aprendendo o desenvolvimento do framework YII do PHP

Estou seguindo um tutorial, em que a pessoa mostra como criar a rota e como cria-la.

Criei meu controler chamado HelloController dentro da pasta controllers

```
   <?php


namespace app\controllers;
use yii\web\Controller;

class HelloController extends Controller
{
    public function actionSaySonething()
    {
        return $this->render('teste',[

        ]); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
    }
}
```

Ai na pasta views criei uma pasta chamada hello com um arquivo chamado teste.php

teste.php

```
<?php

echo 'oi';
```

Reparei que as rotas são chamadas dessa forma:

```
http://localhost/basic/web/index.php?r=site%2Flogin
```

e funciona com os arquivos que vem com o yii, agora quando eu coloco

```
http://localhost/basic/web/index.php?r=hello%2Fteste
```

não encontra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rota no yii é configurada por padrão para ser chamada da seguinte forma `controlador/ação` ou `modulo/controlador/ação`.

Neste seu primeiro exemplo:

```
http://localhost/basic/web/index.php?r=site%2Flogin
```

A rota é o controlador `site` e ação é o `login`, se for olhar no `SiteController` vai existir uma ação chamada `login`.

No segundo exemplo:

```
http://localhost/basic/web/index.php?r=hello%2Fteste
```

Você está solicitando ação `teste` do controlador `hello`, ai que está o problema a ação declarada é a `SaySonething` e solicitando a `teste` que não existe.

A solução do problema é colocar na url `controlador/ação` da seguinte forma:

```
http://localhost/basic/web/index.php?r=hello%2Fsay-sonething
```